# Ubuntu PHP 5.1.2 Upgrade to 5.2.x

Tags: ubuntu, php5

Can anybody offer any pointers as to how to upgrade php 5.1.2 to php 5.2.x on a Plesk VPS Ubuntu server.

Server details are:

Plesk 8.6.0

Ubuntu 6.06

Apache 2.0.55

Current php 5.1.2

Mysql 5.0.22

Not sure if any further information is required - any pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrad it by compiling PHP from the source. Just determine with usual phpinfo() all the options for ./configure for default Plesk PHP and use it to compiling PHP from the source.

Comment: Thanks for the info Drew, just giving that a whirl at the moment.  Everything seems to have run through OK on the make test so hopefully I should be on the home straight.

Comment: OK, make test came back with erros relating output buffering and ArrayObject::exchangeArray.  

Are you able to offer a solution to these.  And once the make test has been run what final steps do I need to take to make this new version of php the current implementation.  I restarted apache and the version is still showing as 5.1.2

Comment: All sorted, had a couple of errors to get passed with Apache loading the module and some features but it's now running the up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

You know what, there's [*still* not a backport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dapper-backports/+bug/78771) for PHP 5.2 in the official [Dapper backports](http://ns2.canonical.com/en/dapper-backports/) repo.

I would upgrade Ubuntu to the next LTS release, 8.04, if possible; most of the time it will Just Work (tm) in place, but a distro upgrade is an invasive procedure and should be tested on a similar system first.

Otherwise, you could try backporting your own packages from a repository like dotdeb, which may well drag in lots of other software you don't want; or installing from source, which is *almost* always more effort than the aforementioned dist-upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

Bit of a newbie when it comes to this sort of thing.  Would it not be possible to install and make the upgraded php package direct?

Comment: Do you mean, build it from source?

Comment: Yes, could I download the source package and re-compile.

Comment: You could - you could even build your own backport by downloading the source from a newer Ubuntu release and compiling a .deb.  That would be my recommendation - mixing source and packaged upgrades is always a bit of a nightmare.